# vertical alignment in amsmath aligned

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, parbox

I have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

     \begin{align*}
     &\pi(x)       & \parbox{8cm}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, harum electram vim ut. Recusabo expetenda sententiae an nam. Ut has laudem graeco invenire. }   \\
     &\psi(y)      & \parbox{8cm}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, harum electram vim ut. Recusabo expetenda sententiae an nam. Ut has laudem graeco invenire. }   \\
     &\tau(z)      & \parbox{8cm}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, harum electram vim ut. Recusabo expetenda sententiae an nam. Ut has laudem graeco invenire. }   \\
     \end{align*} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am trying to explain something about the expresions on the left.
How can I vertically align the expressions with their corresponding explanations?

If mixing amsmath aligned and parbox is not the right approach? What would you suggest?

Comment: `\parbox[t]{8cm}{...}`

Comment: Pronto prontissimo indeed!

Comment: You might consider a different way to present the thing, for instance with a list.

Answer (score 1):

`align` is the wrong environment here, you would be better to use a tabular or a list, a list has the advantage than you can have a page break at the natural point even if that is half way through an item description. the list formatting can be easily controlled using `enumitem` package which I have loaded but just using the default layout here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,enumitem}
\begin{document}

     \begin{tabular}{>$l<$p{8cm}}
     \pi(x)       & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, harum electram vim ut. Recusabo expetenda sententiae an nam. Ut has laudem graeco invenire.    \\
     \psi(y)      & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, harum electram vim ut. Recusabo expetenda sententiae an nam. Ut has laudem graeco invenire.    \\
     \tau(z)      & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, harum electram vim ut. Recusabo expetenda sententiae an nam. Ut has laudem graeco invenire.    \\
     \end{tabular} 


\begin{description}
     \item[$\pi(x)$]  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, harum electram vim ut. Recusabo expetenda sententiae an nam. Ut has laudem graeco invenire.    
     \item[$\psi(y)$]  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, harum electram vim ut. Recusabo expetenda sententiae an nam. Ut has laudem graeco invenire.    
     \item[$\tau(z)$] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, harum electram vim ut. Recusabo expetenda sententiae an nam. Ut has laudem graeco invenire.   
     \end{description} 

\end{document}
```